# Circumference measurement using a capacitive sensor

Tags: electricity, capacitance, geometry, sensor

I have a question which I hope someone in here can help me answer.

Background:
I’m building a device where I intend to use a stretchable capacitive sensor to define the radius change of an object.
Around an object with a given radius (R1), I mount a band made of an none-stretchable material and a stretchable capacitive sensor as the illustration attached. The object tends to grow in circumference (=>R2) and thereby stretching the capacitive sensor more (L2). The idea is, when you stretch the sensor the area changes and thereby change the capacitance.

Problem:
The capacitive sensor has a defined relation between capacitance and stretch when the elongation is done in a linear movement. But when the sensor is wrapped around an object the change in capacitance is caused both by the elongation and the surface pressure between the object and sensor (causing false estimation of L1&L2).
Does anyone have an idea how I can compensate or work around this issue, so that I can define L2=R2

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Martin
[image]

Comment: I would just experimentally calibrate the sensor either by putting it on cylinders of know radii or using some other method to measure the cylinder radius. Attempting to predict the behaviour strikes me as risky without some experimental test of your predictions.